# binary.Read() could not properly read []byte

Tags: go, binary

I'm trying to 'read' a slice of byte to predefined `struct`

```golang
func Test_read_slice(t *testing.T) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer([]uint8{0x00, 0x01, 0xB5})
    type Resp struct {
        Status uint8
        ValueLength uint8 /* The length of the value parameter in bytes. */
        Value []uint8 /* The value. */
    }
    test_data := &Resp{}

    if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &test_data.Status); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not write Status: %v", err)
    }
    if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &test_data.ValueLength); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not write ValueLength %v", err)
    }
    if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, test_data.Value); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Could not write Value %v", err)
    }
    if test_data.Status != 0 || test_data.ValueLength != 1 || len(test_data.Value) != 1 {
        t.Fatalf("Wrong binary values read %+v", test_data)
    }
}
```

For some reason `test_data.Value == nil` but `binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, test_data.Value)` does not fail.
I expect `test_data.Value` to be `[]uint8 {0xB5}`

go 1.21.5

Comment: You need to allocate the slice first to a size that will accommodate incoming data. Alternatively, you read byte by byte. Endinanness does not matter for a byte slice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057783/go-binary-read-into-slice-of-data-gives-zero-result, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101164/converting-an-array-of-byte-to-array-of-int64-golang

Comment: to complete BurakSerdar's comment: in your case, you seem to read the length to read from your input stream, you would just need to allocate a buffer before reading the value: `test_data.Value = make([]uint8, int(test_data.ValueLength))` -- see https://go.dev/play/p/pavG3FgtJ3j